# Hibernate: @ManyToOne by custom query

Tags: hibernate, filtering, many-to-one

I have a table 'AnyEntityReference', which references other entities by two fields: the referenced entity 'type' (i.e. 'Entity1', 'Entity2', ...), and the entity 'key':

```
create table AnyEntityReference (
  type       varchar, /* 'Entity1' or 'Entity2' or 'Entity3' */
  key        varchar  /* if type = 'Entity1' then key to 'Entity1' table etc. */
)

create table Entity1 (
  key        varchar,
  ...
)

create table Entity2 (
  key        varchar,
  ...
)

create table Entity3 (
  key        varchar,
  ...
)
...
```

I need to see these fields as a number of @ManyToOne declarations like this:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "key", insertable=false, updatable=false)
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private Entity1 entity1;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "key", insertable=false, updatable=false)
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private Entity2 entity2;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "key", insertable=false, updatable=false)
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private Entity3 entity3;
...
```

What is missing here is some additional filter, which lets Hibernate to initialize only the one field with matching 'type'.

I think I can use @Where or @Filter annotations, but I do not know how to refer the 'type' field from the reference 'owner'.

Also, I'd like this to be implemented in such a way, so these fields in the 'AnyEntityReference' may be referenced as 'mappedBy' in @OneToMany relations.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code : try below code possible to correct your problem,
if you want get correct solution then specify the table structure.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "KEY", insertable=false, updatable=false)
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private User user;


@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
private Set<Organization> Organization;
```

above code for : single organization has multiple users in relation of table.

Comment: I do not understand your corrections. First, in my case the 'User' and 'Organization' are just examples of entities. They are not connected.

Answer (score 0):

The @JoinFormula works almost well:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinFormula(value="(SELECT u.key FROM Entity1 u WHERE type = 'Entity1' and u.key = key)",
  referencedColumnName="key")
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private @Nullable Entity1 entity1;
```

The only little problem it that Hibernate does not support (crashes) when I try using these fields as 'mappedBy' in @OneToMany relations.

Comment: This worked fro me. But seems `@OneToOne` mapping also doesn't work like this.

Answer (score 0):

As the title of a book "Thinking in Java", I think the best solution for your problem is polymorphism. something like this:

```
   @Entity
   @Table("AnyEntityReference")
   public class AnyEntityReference {
      ...
      @JoinColumn(name = "key", insertable=false, updatable=false)
      @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
      private Entity entity;
      ...
    }

    // Base class
    @Entity
    @Inheritance(strategy=SINGLE_TABLE)
    public class Entity {
      ...
      @Id
      private String key;
      ...
    }

    //Child Classes
    @Entity
    public class EntityType1 extends Entity {
      ...
    }

    @Entity
    public class EntityType2 extends Entity {
      ...
    }

    @Entity   
    public class EntityType3 extends Entity {
      ...
    }
```

In this way, you just have a reference of Entity (base class) and you can use polymorphism to handle each object.

I share you some links about this.

> https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13981_01/cmp30cfg016.htm
>   https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/inheritance.html

I hope this information help you.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, Hector. I see the idea. Unfortunately it will not work in my case. I'm dealing with a legacy DB, all key columns in entities are named after their corresponding tables, so I cannot declare them in the base class with a single @Id.